# Proving (p->q)->(~q->~p) using Coq Proof Assistant

Tags: logic, coq, theorem-proving

I am fairly new to Coq and am trying out sample lemmas from Ruth and Ryan. The proof using natural deduction is pretty trivial, and this is what I want to prove using Coq.

```
assume p -> q.
  assume ~q.
    assume p.
      q.
      False.
    therefore ~p.
  therefore ~q -> ~p.
therefore (p -> q) => ~q => ~p.
```

I am stuck at the line 3 `assume p`.

Can someone please tell me if there is an one-to-one mapping from natural deduction to Coq keywords?

Answer (score 4):

`NNPP` is useless !

```
Theorem easy : forall p q:Prop, (p->q)->(~q->~p).
Proof. intros. intro. apply H0. apply H. exact H1. Qed.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can start your proof like this:

```
Section CONTRA.
Variables P Q : Prop.

Hypothesis PimpQ : P -> Q.
Hypothesis notQ  : ~Q.
Hypothesis Ptrue : P.

Theorem contra : False.
Proof.
```

Here is the environment at that point:

```
1 subgoal

  P : Prop
  Q : Prop
  PimpQ : P -> Q
  notQ : ~ Q
  Ptrue : P
  ============================
   False
```

You should be able to continue the proof. It will be a bit more verbose than your proof (on line 4 you just wrote q, here you will have to prove it by combining `PimpQ` and `Ptrue`. It should be fairly `trivial` though... :)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I figured it out about an hour after I posted the question. The solution is posted below. Ha ha!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to give you the whole solution since it's easy and that's how you learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not that difficult, actually.

Just played around, introduced a double negation, and things fell flat automatically. This is how the proof looks like.

```
Theorem T1 : (~q->~p)->(p->q).
Proof.
intros.
apply NNPP.
intro.
apply H in H1.
contradiction.
Qed.
```

Ta daaaa!